# How to check deadlock in this example

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock

currently I am learning deadlock and I found a example of deadlock but I don't get how deadlock is occurring in this example.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final PolitePerson jane = new PolitePerson("Jane");
        final PolitePerson john = new PolitePerson("John");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 jane.sayHello(john);
            }
        }).start();

       new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                john.sayHello(jane);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    static class PolitePerson {
        private final String name;

        public PolitePerson(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public synchronized void sayHello(PolitePerson person){
            System.out.format("%s: %s" + " has said hello to me!%n", this.name, person.getName());

            person.sayHelloBack(this);
        }

        public synchronized void sayHelloBack(PolitePerson person) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s" + " has said hello back to me!%n", this.name, person.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

I spend more then one hour understanding how things are happening here but didn't got it.
here is the output which I am getting

```
Jane: John has said hello to me!
John: Jane has said hello to me!
```

or maybe I misunderstood synchronisation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method marked with `synchronized` locks the critical-section (the method) using `this` as the lock. To enter a critical section (and lock it), a thread needs to acquire the corresponding lock. If the section is already locked, the thread is blocked at the entrance and waits for the lock to be released.

A and B are threads:

- A calls `jane.sayHello(john)` and locks `jane`.
- B calls `john.sayHello(jane)` and locks `john`.

Notice that `sayHello` is marked with `synchronized`.

- A calls `person.sayHelloBack(this)`, where `person` is `john`.
- B calls `person.sayHelloBack(this)`, where `person` is `jane`.

Notice that `sayHelloBack` is also marked with `synchronized`.

- B holds `john`, so A's call `john.sayHelloBack` is blocked.
- A holds `jane`, so B's call `jane.sayHelloBack` is blocked.
- A is waiting for B to release the lock and vice versa.
- Deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

When we mark a method as `synchronized`, it takes a lock on the current object. So, the first thread takes a lock on the object `jane` whereas the second thread takes lock on the object `john`, as soon as it calls the method `sayHello()`.

As you have marked the `sayHelloBack()` also as synchronized, it would wait until the other thread releases lock on the invoking object. For the first thread, it calls `john.sayHelloBack()`, it tries to acquire lock on `john` - but it has already been acquired by `thread-2`. For the second thread, it calls `jane.sayHellpBack()`, it tries to acquire lock on `jane` - but it is already acquired by `thread-1`.

So, both the threads keep waiting for the lock at that point causing the deadlock.